# ASP.Net MVC List of User and their Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2

I'm using ASP.NET MVC Default project. In there we have a database called **AspNetRoles** (defines roles like Admin, User)
[image: Role Database]

then there's a database called **AspNetUsers** which just defines Users when you register them [image: User Database]

and the last and most important is **AspNetUserRoles**. When you assign Roles to the User here is where it is placed (and the Id's are hashed)

[image: UserRole Database]

My question is, how do I get a list of every user on the system and their roles? I can't figure out how to start doing this. Should I create my own User and Role database and forget about the default one? Or is there a way of creating with the default ones?

---

*Also, I would keep in mind that as of now I'm assigning Roles when
 registering (User by default) and later when I create the Index where
 I show the list of Users and Roles, I will want to edit them, but this
 is just a disclaimer.
Thank you very much for any type of help.*

Comment: Role List of Every user? or the user whos logged in?

Comment: List of Every User.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM AspNetUsers` would prob be a good start...What exactly don't you understand here? *Should I create my own User and Role database* eh? why? What's wrong with the one you've got?

Comment: nothing's wrong with it, I've just many tutorials using their own, and I though maybe that's good practice and just wanted to ask that.

Comment: I think you need to read up on this subject some more.

Comment: I agree with you, that's why I wrote here, to get help and information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no built in methods for retrieving the list of users with their roles so you can try to get the user and their role like below (using EF):

```
var list = context.Users        
    .Where(x => x.Roles.Select(a => a.Id))
    .ToList();
```

Using this you get every users and assigned roles.

**Update**
Create a Model like below first:

```
public class UserRoleInfo
{
    public ApplicationUser User { set; get; }
    public List<string> Roles { set; get; } 
}
```

Then Your Query would be like (Query Syntax):

```
var listOfUsers = (from u in db.Users
             let query = (from ur in db.Set<IdentityUserRole>()
                          where ur.UserId.Equals(u.Id)
                          join r in db.Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id select r.Name)
                          select new UserRoleInfo() {User = u, Roles = query.ToList<string>()})
                         .ToList();
```

Query above will return Every User With their Roles no matter how many.

**UPDATE**

Your view would be like:

```
@model UserRoleInfo
    <table>
        <tbody>
@foreach (var user in Model)
{
    var appUser = user.ApplicationUser;
    var roles = user.Roles;

            <tr>
                <td>
                    @appUser.Email
                </td>
                <td>
                    @string.Join(",", roles)
                </td>
            </tr>

}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I forgot to tell, but yes, I am using Entity Framework. And this method wont work because it will just show the Id (hashed Id), which isn't very pleasing.

Comment: *show the Id (hashed Id), which isn't very pleasing.* well don't show it then?!

Comment: @B.Zab you can do the desired select. this is only an example. what do you want to return?

Comment: @ecKO I want to show UserName(email) and their assigned Role. But as far as I can see now, it's not that hard. Where do I write this method though?

Comment: @B.Zab have you tried this query? this query returns an list of `ApplicationUser` and Roles if you only want to return names and role do another select returning them.

Comment: like `Roles.Select(a => a.Name)`

Comment: @ecKO impatiently waiting.

Comment: how could I modify the code to use not Roles List but Role as one, because in my application Users only have one Role, not a list of them. And because of that I can't Display the data in the View.

Comment: @B.Zab there is a solution for that adding a property called RoleName to your ApplicationUser (extend your ApplicationUser) then you can simple pass the role name to user and get users and their role that way, but its just an idea. but i still recommend using this way, because later you will be needing to have multiple roles for a user and wanting to show them would be kinda hard as now, i will edit my post and show how to show them within your view as well.

Comment: @ecKo Oh, didn't see it, now I see, will try it the next day because I'm away from my computer. But as I'm seeing it now, I think it will work. Thank you very much for your help, you helped a lot!

Comment: @B.Zab you are welcome, don't forget to vote up and accept if it was the solution ;)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest going this way since this will return all users from database as a list with their respective roles attached in the user object.
Furthermore it uses eagerly loading on Roles entity, so it will be converted to a join in database.

If you want to take only one user and its roles where is just a `where` condition to add and filter by its id.

```
var users = _applicationDbContext.Users.Include(x => x.Roles).ToList();
foreach (var applicationUser in users)
{
    var userRoles = applicationUser.Roles;
    //Do something with this user roles
}
```

Answer (score -4):

to get a list of every user on the system and their roles:

```
SELECT        UserRoleId, UserId, RoleId, dbo.GetRoleName(RoleId) AS RoleName
FROM            dbo.UserRoles
```

Function : dbo.GetRoleName -

```
function [dbo].[GetRoleName](@input int)
Returns Nvarchar(500)
As
Begin
Declare @RoleName nvarchar(500)
Set @RoleName=(select Name from Roles where RoleId=@input)
return @RoleName
End
```

Comment: Is that a SQL function? Why would you create a SQL function to do a SELECT? What's wrong with SELECT? Or maybe INNER JOIN?